# Is there a Mathematica function that puts a list of numbers in a normalized [1, 10[ scale

Tags: list-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation

I have the following list:

```
{{{R1 -> 51297.1, R2 -> 7715.57, CC1 -> 1.*10^-9, CC2 -> 1.*10^-9, 
   Rf -> 65766.1, Rg -> 7715.57}, {R1 -> 7210.42, R2 -> 59467.7, 
   CC3 -> 1.*10^-9, CC4 -> 1.*10^-9, R5 -> 16940.1}, {R1 -> 55232.9, 
   R2 -> 26034.5, CC1 -> 1.*10^-9, CC2 -> 1.*10^-9, Rf -> 63738.1, 
   Rg -> 26034.5}, {R1 -> 10483.7, R2 -> 2293.26, CC3 -> 1.*10^-9, 
   CC4 -> 1.*10^-9, R5 -> 41666.7}, {R1 -> 11016.6, R2 -> 68946.5, 
   CC3 -> 1.*10^-9, CC4 -> 1.*10^-9, R5 -> 210339.}}}
```

I want to create a copy of this list and normalize the values to a scale of [1, 10[. Does Mathematica have any sort of normalization function?

Thank you!

EDIT:

Sorry I need to make thios clear, as my use of the word normalization was apparently wrong here. I basically want the result to be the numbers multiplied/divided in a 1-10 scale.

```
{{{R1 -> 5.12971, R2 -> 7.71557, CC1 -> 1, CC2 -> 1, 
   Rf -> 6.57661, Rg -> 7.71557}, {R1 -> 7.21042, R2 -> 5.94677, 
   CC3 -> 1, CC4 -> 1, R5 -> 1.69401}, {R1 -> 5.52329, 
   R2 -> 2.60345, CC1 -> 1, CC2 -> 1, Rf -> 6.37381, 
   Rg -> 2.60345}, {R1 -> 1.04837, R2 -> 2.29326, CC3 -> 1, 
   CC4 -> 1, R5 -> 4.16667}, {R1 -> 1.10166, R2 -> 6.89465, 
   CC3 -> 1, CC4 -> 1, R5 -> 2.10339}}}
```

So something like putting the numbers in scientific notation and conserving only the number, without the power of 10.

Comment: It is not entirely clear how you want to normalize the values. Do you want them to be normalized across the whole multi-level list, or only across "one row"? And yes, there is a function for rescaling: [`Rescale`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rescale.html).

Comment: `Rescale` general rescales in a closed interval $[a,b]$, not a half-open one $[a,b[$.  Is that acceptable?

Comment: @MichaelE2 sorry my question was unclear, I had other meaning for normalization in my head, edited it.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I think you are looking for what we called in school the "mantissa."  See if my answer accomplishes what you seek.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps `MantissaExponent`?:

```
{{{R1 -> 51297.1, R2 -> 7715.57, CC1 -> 1.*10^-9, CC2 -> 1.*10^-9, 
    Rf -> 65766.1, Rg -> 7715.57}, {R1 -> 7210.42, R2 -> 59467.7, 
    CC3 -> 1.*10^-9, CC4 -> 1.*10^-9, R5 -> 16940.1}, {R1 -> 55232.9, 
    R2 -> 26034.5, CC1 -> 1.*10^-9, CC2 -> 1.*10^-9, Rf -> 63738.1, 
    Rg -> 26034.5}, {R1 -> 10483.7, R2 -> 2293.26, CC3 -> 1.*10^-9, 
    CC4 -> 1.*10^-9, R5 -> 41666.7}, {R1 -> 11016.6, R2 -> 68946.5, 
    CC3 -> 1.*10^-9, CC4 -> 1.*10^-9, R5 -> 210339.}}} /. 
 x_?NumberQ :> 10*First@MantissaExponent[x]

(*
{{{R1 -> 5.12971, R2 -> 7.71557, CC1 -> 1., CC2 -> 1., Rf -> 6.57661, 
   Rg -> 7.71557}, {R1 -> 7.21042, R2 -> 5.94677, CC3 -> 1., 
   CC4 -> 1., R5 -> 1.69401}, {R1 -> 5.52329, R2 -> 2.60345, 
   CC1 -> 1., CC2 -> 1., Rf -> 6.37381, 
   Rg -> 2.60345}, {R1 -> 1.04837, R2 -> 2.29326, CC3 -> 1., 
   CC4 -> 1., R5 -> 4.16667}, {R1 -> 1.10166, R2 -> 6.89465, 
   CC3 -> 1., CC4 -> 1., R5 -> 2.10339}}
*)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Michael! That was exactly what I was looking for. Can you just please explain me what the "First" is doing there? Also can I also store the exponent? How would you then convert back to the expressions? My intention is to take this numbers, approximate them to the closest values on a list and then go back to the original numbers

Comment: @GrangerObliviate `First` extracts the mantissa (see docs for `MantissaExponent` or just execute it on a number of your choosing to see the output). The mantissa you get is 1/10 of your desired one. Therefore I multiply by `10`.  You can store the exponent by omitting first. You might define your own function to give the form you seek (something like `mantExp[x_]:=Module[{m,e}, {m,e}=MantissaExponent[x];{10m,e-1}];`)

Answer (score 0):

Try using:  `Rescale[#,{1,10}] &`